# Custom color for LaTeX output in Sphinx documentation package

Tags: color, preamble, inline, mathjax, sphinx

I am trying to customize the color of the LaTeX inline formula when using Sphinx documentation package, and html output.

### The details:

I have a file called `func.rst`, which includes the following line:

```
Let :math:`x_{1}` be a binary variable.
```

which is rendered successfully into LaTeX in the documentation I created with Sphinx.

(I have `'sphinx.ext.imgmath'` listed in `extensions` in `conf.py`)

***My goal is to have `x_{1}` colored in red.***

### Things I tried:

1. Adding the color inside the formula:

   ```
   Let :math:`\color{red}x_{1}` be a binary variable.
   ```

   while also defining

   ```
   latex_elements['preamble'] = '\usepackage{xcolor}'
   ```

   in the `conf.py` file.
2. Trying to define all math output globally with:

   ```
   latex_elements['preamble'] = r'''
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \everymath{\color{red}}
   \everydisplay{\color{red}}
   '''
   ```

Needless to say, both (and many more less promising ideas) failed.

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: you are using mathjax not latex, so `\usepackage` etc do not work and unfortunately by default mathjax uses the wrong syntax for color, try `\color{red}{x_{1}}`

Comment: I still get an error "Undefined control sequence...". Anywhere I should declare the use of colors?

Comment: that sounds like a latex error, are you not getting pdf output (which does use latex) for mathjax the wrong color is defined by default or  you can use the color extension to fix it http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=latex#color

Comment: (1) The file in which this formula exists is a `.rst` file, that is rendered using the `conf.py` file. These do not conform to the "usual" LaTeX (etc.) documents, and configurations are set in a different way. e.g., latex is converted to `.png` and then presented inside the html as images. (2) Your suggestion to use the mathjx syntax gave the same error as the one given by the latex syntex.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440108/custom-color-for-latex-output-in-sphinx-documentation-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to be targeting html with math rendered as PNGs images (or SVGs), the current config value to configure isn't `latex_elements`, but [`imgmath_latex_preamble`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/math.html#confval-imgmath_latex_preamble).

Notice that this question is not TeX/LaTeX directly related but mainly one on usage of [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org). See [sphinx-users](https://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-users) mailing list (there is a Gmane interface under the `gmane.comp.python.sphinx.user` (`news://news.gmane.org:119/gmane.comp.python.sphinx.user`)

Ah I see now that this question is a cross-posted exact copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440108/custom-color-for-latex-output-in-sphinx-documentation-package